# Owncloud https and ssl with free dns

Tags: ssl, https, owncloud, noip

I use no-ip and I want to set my owncloud server (hosted with raspberry) with https protocol.

After installed everything I follow this from the official documentation:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName my_no-ip_address
   Redirect permanent / https://my_no-ip_address/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName my_no-ip_address
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload"
    </IfModule>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Now this is what happen when I try to connect to my owncloud with the following address:

```
http://192.168.x.x/owncloud   (local address)   - It works
https://192.168.x.x/owncloud   (local address)   - It works

http://my_no-ip_address/owncloud   (no-ip address)   - It works
https://my_no-ip_address/owncloud   (no-ip address)   - It doesn't work (403 forbidden)
```

I'm thinking that this is caused by no-ip service because I have a free account.

Did I do something wrong or is no-ip problem? Are there other free dns which allow me to use https ?

Comment: This should not be a problem with using no-ip.  How does it not work?  What error message do you get?  Did you generate your own certificate?  If so, how?  What CN did you use?

Comment: @heavyd I get a 403 Forbidden, I did what I posted

Comment: Right now it looks like you are just serving your files over HTTP on port 443 (you're not actually using HTTPS/SSL/TLS).  Now, that doesn't explain why you're getting a 403, but note that you do have that problem as well.  You will need to use the `SSLEngine on` on directive to enable SSL, but you'll also need SSL certificates... that is a much larger discussion to which there are lots of guides out there.

Comment: @heavyd I don't know why with local address it works. could you provide me a guide to enable this?